# dattabricks instance profile undefined on worker node

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, databricks, aws-databricks

I have a databricks cluster with an instance profile giving access to certain AWS S3 buckets.

This works fine on the master node. However, when my python user defined function on the workers needs to interact with S3 the profile is undefined and I get the following error on the executor:

```
AWSCredentialProviderList:V3: No credentials provided by shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.BasicAWSCredentialsProvider: shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.CredentialInitializationException: Access key or secret key is null
```

How can the access keys be distributed (without me having to hardcode them)?